# Problem at gradle wrapper 5.2.1 build inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, gradle, gradlew

I'm facing a problem during the attempt to run my gradle project inside a docker container using gradle wrapper. The message shown in the moment that I try to run my build is:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project ''.
> The project name must not be empty. Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement (see https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[]) for more details).
```

I've tried many approaches to solve that including the documentation link in the error message: [https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[])](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) but it didn't work anyway.

My `settings.gradle` file:

`rootProject.name = 'ui-serenity'`

Acctually I dont have a include statement at my `build.gradle` file, I tried this approach too but without success.

The curious is that at my Jenkins envienronment its work fine, and the project is successfully executed. But I have to do some ajustments and in my PC it have to run as well.

Comment: Are you sure you have copied `settings.gradle` file into the image before trying to build?

Comment: Yes @michalk I'm sure. I've mapped my local directory to my container using volume.

My docker run command:
`docker run -v /home/my_username/folder/ui-serenity/:/workspace/psau/ --rm -i serenity-docker:serenity-docker /workspace/psau/gradlew clean test`

When I attach to my container and view /workspace/psau (root directory) they contains all my project files, including `settings.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're running Gradle from the root directory. Inside your container, try first `cd`ing into your app code directory before running gradle.